# Datatables lengthmenu issue

Tags: javascript, datatables

Is there a way for the data tables length menu to not count collapsed rows?
I need the hidden rows to be included in my table in the background but I don't want the customers getting confused by the "show 10 entries" menu when they see 1 row on their end because I have 9 hidden rows

for example here http://live.datatables.net/hufojaki/1/edit

I have the other rows visibility set to "collapse" because I don't want users to see those rows, however, I do still need those row data so that when I export the table to excel or pdf, those data would still be included. but the pagination and the length menu are getting messed up because of this.

What would be a workaround for this so that the length menu would only count the rows the users need to see?

Comment: I don't know of any way to handle this situation directly in DataTables - because DataTables will report on the rows it contains, regardless of how you choose to alter the appearance of those rows in the DOM.  Can the user ever unhide any of these hidden rows (or hide more rows)? Can you clarify why such rows might exist in the first place?